# Activation of network connection failed (VLAN)

Tags: windows, ethernet, vlan

I'm trying to set up a VLAN to test an issue. I have the following:

1. A dell laptop running windows 7
2. A lenovo notebook running ubuntu from live USB with some storage preserved on it
3. A tp-link TL-SG105E switch set up to have VLAN with the id 100

Everything's working fine with the windows system and the switch but the ubuntu system keeps saying it cannot connect to the ethernet connection. I made the following settings on the ubuntu system to set it up for my VLAN:

```
sudo ip link add link eth0 name enp0s25 type vlan egress 0:7 id 100
sudo ip addr add dev ctlvlan 172.16.32.20/24
```

However the ethernet connection issue was present already before making the steps above. My wifi connection on the ubuntu system works perfectly, it's just the ethernet not being able to connect. I'm pretty much new to ubuntu so I'd like to ask for your advice on the issue. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sudo ip link add link eth0 name enp0s25 type vlan egress 0:7 id 100
> sudo ip addr add dev ctlvlan 172.16.32.20/24
> ```

Is the problem. The commands are not internally consistent.

First, find adapter name:

```
 ip link
```

This will show you the interfaces. Note down the correct name of the interface. Then create vlan

```
 sudo ip link add link interfacename name vlan100 type vlan id 100
```

This will create a new interface named `vlan100` on `interfacename` with vlan 100.

Next, set an IP:

```
sudo ip addr add dev vlan100 172.16.32.20/24
```

You used different device names for the same thing, with no internal consistency.